# pass multiple values to JS

Tags: javascript, asp.net

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="checkBoxes" onclick="Utility('<%# Eval("id") %>');" />
```

The onclick runing the JS

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
             var SelectedUtilityId = -1;
             var UtilityCompanyId = -1;

             function Utility(id) {
                 SelectedUtilityId = id;
                 UtilityCompanyId = UtilityCompanyId;
                 WorkItemMgr.DisplayLabelIfTrue(SelectedUtilityId, UtilityCompanyId);
             }
```

The Eval("id") binding to the Id, but I also want to bind to the UtilityCompanyId, as I want to pass that value to the JS as well...how is this done?

Thanks

Comment: Where would this other value come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the function and the call to it to pass a second value. E.g.,

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkBoxes" onclick="Utility('<%# Eval("id") %>', '<%# someOtherValueHere %>');" />
```

and

```
function Utility(id, otherId) {
    SelectedUtilityId = id;
    UtilityCompanyId = otherId;
    WorkItemMgr.DisplayLabelIfTrue(SelectedUtilityId, UtilityCompanyId);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="checkBoxes" onclick="Utility('<%# Eval("id") %>','<%# Eval("UtilityCompanyId") %>');" />
```

In General:

```
onclick="Utility('<%# Eval("val1") %>','<%# Eval("val2") %>','<%# Eval("val3") %>');"  etc
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="checkBoxes" onclick="Utility('<%# Eval("id") %>',"-1");" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Well just add extra parameters to the function and pass them in the onclick?

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkBoxes" onclick="Utility(<%# Eval("id") %>,<%# Eval("other_thing") %>);" />
```

and

```
function Utility(id, other_thing) {
                 SelectedUtilityId = id;
                 UtilityCompanyId = other_thing;
                 WorkItemMgr.DisplayLabelIfTrue(SelectedUtilityId, UtilityCompanyId);
             }
```